# Play audio base64 string in Internet Explorer

Tags: html, audio, base64

How to play audio with the `base64-string` in Internet Explorer?
Code

```
audio =   $("#sound1")[0];
audio.src = "data:audio/wav;base64," + reader.result;
// reader.result - строка UklGRhIqBQBXQVZFZm10IBIAAAAHA...
//audio.src = "somerecord.wav";
audio.load();
```

Works correctly in Chrome, but not in IE.
Another way is create file and play it in IE. But how to do that without store file on disk?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for an IE alone fix, the below code might help.

```
window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(recordedBlob, fileName, { type: recordingType });
```

where `recordedBlob` is the blob URL (Using the base64-string you can create one blob URL, a sample for the same is available [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16245767/creating-a-blob-from-a-base64-string-in-javascript)),

`fileName` is the name of the output file &

`recordingType` could be a JSON value like "audio/mp3"